# SVG Rounding Bug

Tags: html, css, svg

Chrome's way of rounding sub-pixel values in SVGs creates a problem for me.
Is there any way to fix this problem? Because I use opacity I'm not able to simply add a dark background to remove the white glimps.

Here's the example:
http://dabblet.com/gist/766f6a238d00bcbb41d4

Comment: You'd be better filling a bug against chrome itself - so that they could fix it in a fututre version -i nstead of opennng another chain of special-cases everyone coding for the web must be aware: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @jsbueno Sub-pixel rendering issues are known for years, and not only in SVG: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/ This is not really a bug of Chrome, it's a rounding problem. So it's always quality vs. speed and there will never be "one" solution. I was looking for answers like Michael's below.

Comment: When it comes to **opacity** I'm sure there is no way to solve this. Please notify me if any but it hardly happens. Even the solution of Michael.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter to add "grout" into the gap :) But it's a hack that works by increasing the opacity of those pixels. It will also roughen up the anti-aliasing of our other edges. Also if you're using opacity in these gradients then you will need to adjust those tableValues below to the range that you want (aka if your fill is 0.4 opacity, then your tableValues would look like "0 .1 .4 .4 .4"). If you have variable opacity in your gradients, then you can play around with other types of component transfers that will preserve the opacity gradients better.

```
<svg id="background-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 150 75" >
  <defs>
    <linearGradient y2="1" x2="1" y1="0" x1="0" id="triangleGradient">
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
        <stop stop-color="blue" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <filter id="mynameisgrout">
       <feComponentTransfer>
         <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 .25 1 1 1"/>
       </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
   </defs>

   <g filter="url(#mynameisgrout)">
     <polygon points="0,75 100,75 50,0" fill="url(#triangleGradient)"></polygon>
     <polygon points="50,0 150,0 100,75" fill="url(#triangleGradient)"></polygon>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not perfect, but very interesting. I'll be reading some docs tomorrow about this. Thanks!

Comment: I found a way better solution now :)

Answer (score 0):

The SVG shape rendering option allows to configure what's important for rendering.
In this case *shape-rendering="crispEdges"* solves the problem.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

Comment: I tried shape-rendering first, but it still left a faint line on Firefox/WIndows 8, but perhaps I made a syntax error :)

Comment: It's still not perfect, but there just seems to be no perfect solution. Grout introduces other problems, the colors seem to sometimes change strangely. Also while the shape-rendering option creates a perfect result in Chrome and a pretty good one in Firefox, I had to disable it for Safari and in IE it seems to just have no effect. The whole thing is way more complex then I thought when I decided to use SVG.

Comment: Ah. You can fix the color problem by adding color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" to the filter element. The silent default is broken in Safari. But yes - there are many bugs and broken implementations once you start using more advanced SVG.

Comment: Haha, if I had new what I know now I would have used a pngs instead. Anyway, I got a good enough quality now :)